# Syntax Error when searching all fields of sql table

Tags: sql, delphi, search, syntax, syntax-error

I am creating a search filter for my sql table and I want to be able to search all the fields of the table and return records that contain the text I have entered. I have multiple tables so hardcoding all the fields into my statement is not an option. I tried this method (see code snippit) but I am getting this error:

> class EOIeException with message 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(fieldContent LIKE '%SearchStr%')
>   OR (fieldContent LIKE '%SearchStr%')
>   OR ''. Process stopped.

Normally a syntax error is easy to solve but I don't have a clue with this one. Hope you can help. Thanks. Btw the fieldContent and SearchStr is just representations of the actual content.

```
qryInfo.SQL.Clear;
qryInfo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + tableName);
qryInfo.Open;

tblInfo.SQL.Clear;
tblInfo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + tableName);
tblInfo.SQL.Add('WHERE (' + qryInfo.Fields[0].AsString + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%' + edtSearch.Text + '%') + ')');

for i:= 1 to qryInfo.FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    tblInfo.SQL.Add(' OR (' + qryInfo.Fields[i].AsString + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%' + edtSearch.Text + '%') + ')');
  end;
tblInfo.Open;
```

When putting ShowMessage(tblInfo.Text) before tblInfo.Open I get

```
 SELECT * FROM tblGymnast
 WHERE (EG000002 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (Erasmus LIKE '%S%')
 OR (Petrus LIKE '%S%')
 OR (Peter LIKE '%S%')
 OR (EF000001 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (2 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (0832133123 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (SFEW33FWX LIKE '%S%')
 OR (- LIKE '%S%')
 OR (2016/03/08 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (1996-08-19 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (M LIKE '%S%')
 OR (Afrikaans LIKE '%S%')
 OR (White LIKE '%S%')
 OR (Trampoline LIKE '%S%')
 OR (1908966000234 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (EL000004 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (ES000002 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (EL000003 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (TR000002 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (ED000001 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (234567890 LIKE '%S%')
 OR (EM000001 LIKE '%S%')
```

Comment: Just before `tblInfo.Open;`, add  `ShowMessage(tblInfo.SQL.Text);` and see if you get what you expect. Also, do some research on SQL Injection - you've left yourself wide open  by using unsanitized user input to concatenate SQL. [Little Bobby Tables](http://littlebobbytables.com) would love you.

Comment: Hi, Ken I edited my question with the results of ShowMessage(tblInfo.SQL.Text). It is giving out correct result. Also, would strings that are enclosed in QoutedStr() still pose a liability in regards to SQL injection? @KenWhite

Comment: Yes, strings enclosed in QuotedStr() are very much vulnerable to SQL Injection. Did you read the link I gave you? Your SQL is not *giving out correct result*. I see at least 6 issues with the SQL you added - `2`, `0832133123`,  `-`, `2016-03/08`, and `1996-08-19`, `1908966000234`, and `234567890` are not valid column names in any SQL dialect I've ever encountered. If your SQL will not execute in a management utility that lets you run it for testing, it will not run in your Delphi app either.

Comment: Yes I did follow the link. Thanks for the reply and your response. Those strings that you pointed out as being invalid column names is in fact the strings contained in the first row of each column. Why is qryInfo.Fields[i].AsString returning the information contained in the table and not the column names?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit to add the generated SQL, the error in your code became very clear.  (The generated SQL contained invalid column names, and your subsequent comment after I pointed that out confirms that it is in fact data.)

You're trying to retrieve the column names as the left-hand value of the statements using `Field[i].AsString`, but this is wrong. `TField.AsString` returns the field's **content** as a string, not the field's **name**. To retrieve the name, you need to use `TField.FieldName` instead.

```
qryInfo.SQL.Clear;
qryInfo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + tableName);
qryInfo.Open;

tblInfo.SQL.Clear;
tblInfo.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + tableName);
tblInfo.SQL.Add('WHERE (' + qryInfo.Fields[0].FieldName + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%' + edtSearch.Text + '%') + ')');

for i:= 1 to qryInfo.FieldCount - 1 do
begin
  tblInfo.SQL.Add(' OR (' + qryInfo.Fields[i].FieldName + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%' + edtSearch.Text + '%') + ')');
end;
tblInfo.Open;
```

I'm going to point out that this code is **extremely vulnerable** to SQL injection, because it blindly uses unsanitized user data to concatenate the SQL statement. This is a terribly bad idea, as it puts your entire database at risk. Use of `QuotedStr` does absolutely nothing to reduce that risk. See [Little Bobby Tables](http://littlebobbytables.com) for information about why this is such a security risk.

Comment: Thanks that solves the error. I know it is valnerable but at the moment that is not a concern of mine. This is a school project and I am focusing on other aspects of the design first and will later fokus on securing from injection. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Quick question @Ken White, how do you use parameters with a LIKE statement such as %:Parameter%

Comment: You use `:Parameter`, and set the parameter with `'%' + ParamValue + '%'` in your code.